# How to persist data object in JBPM 7.9

Tags: jbpm, kie

I'm now trying to use the new jbpm 7.9.
I have a problem that my custom data object is not saved in my database. Below are my steps:

1. Create a persistable data object
2. Create a simple process which used the data object as a process variable
3. Modify the project settings Persistence section.

   1. Change to a datasouce, mysql, already defined in the app server.
   2. Add the data object to "Project Persistable Data Objects"
   3. Change the dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
4. Deploy to one kie server.
5. Start a process instance either by UI or rest API. It completes successfully and I can see the variable is created correctly in the process manager UI.

But after I check the database, there's neither the table nor my record.
Do I make something wrong?
[image: The seetings]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I find the answer by myself.

I need to define additional marshalling strategy

```
<marshalling-strategy>
            <resolver>mvel</resolver>
            <identifier>new org.drools.persistence.jpa.marshaller.JPAPlaceholderResolverStrategy("com.myteam:xerox:1.0.0", classLoader)</identifier>
            <parameters/>
</marshalling-strategy>
```

This is not mentioned in the document anywhere. :(

Comment: Thanks, I faced the same problem and solved by your answer

Comment: The latest [JBPM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.42.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/) fully documents this under [Persistence and Transactions](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.42.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_jbpmpersistence) specifically [Persisting process variables in a separate database schema in jBPM](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.42.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#process-variables-persist-proc_business-processes)